# How to retrieve the parameter after a hash (#) with React Router and useParams hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a route like

```js
<Route path="/search/:slug"><SearchPage /></Route>
```

in my React Router. SearchPage is a component that uses the `useParams()` hook provided by `react-router-dom`.

```js
// SearchPage.js
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

export function SearchPage(props) {
    const { slug } = useParams();
    console.log(slug)
    // ...do other stuff
}
```

However, when I navigate to `/search/foo#bar`, the SearchPage component only receives `foo` in the `slug`. It is possible for my component to receive the full `foo#bar`, or, better yet, `foo` and `bar` separately?

Comment: I think the `useLocation` hook from `react-router-dom`. Something like `const {hash} = useLocation()`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to use [`useLocation`](https://reactrouter.com/native/api/Hooks/uselocation) hook and get the `hash` from there. First step is to import `useLocation` from `react-router-dom`:

```
import useLocation from "react-router-dom";
```

Inside the component function, use this:

```
const { hash } = useLocation();
```

---

From the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/native/api/Hooks/uselocation):

> [**`useLocation`**](https://reactrouter.com/native/api/Hooks/uselocation)
>
> The `useLocation` hook returns the [`location`](https://reactrouter.com/native/api/location) object that represents the current URL. You can think about it like a `useState` that returns a new `location` whenever the URL changes.
>
> This could be really useful e.g. in a situation where you would like to trigger a new “page view” event using your web analytics tool whenever a new page loads

Answer (score 0):

In a URL like this: "/myUrl/products/product12?myQuery=12#myHash"
The UseParams will return everything up to the query e.g "/myUrl/products/product12" but not the query "?myQuery=12#myHash".

React has a hook for this "useLocation". Use Location will give you an object with 4 things but only 3 that you need to worry about for this example, (
"pathname": "/myUrl/products/product12",
"search": "myQuery=12",
"hash": "myHash")

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
const QueryDetails = () => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const myQuery  = location.search;

return (
        <div className='container mt-2'>
           <p>{myQuery}</p>
        </div>
    );
}
 
export default QueryDetails;
```

Comment: I am not sure whether you answered it in the context of answer given by @Praveen Kumar Purushothaman but `const { hash } = useLocation();` works even if I have `?myQuery=12#myHash` in the url after `/myUrl/products/product12`